# Scanning into struct of gorm query

Tags: go, go-gorm

I'm trying to scan the result of a query into a res structure.

The code builds and the query passes but the result array consists of default values like this:

> [{0 0 0} {0 0 0} {0 0 0} {0 0 0} {0 0 0} {0 0 0}]

Also, result array has the exact length as the query result should have.
When i try generated query in postgres shell it returns the result correctly.

Code:

```
 type res struct{
    id int
    number int
    user_id int
    }
    
    func getDataJoin(){
        new := []res{}
        db.Db.Table("users").Select("users.id as id, credit_cards.number as number, credit_cards.user_id as user_id").Joins("left join credit_cards on credit_cards.user_id = users.id").Scan(&new)
        fmt.Println("user\n",new)
    }
```

Generated Query:

```
SELECT users.id as id, credit_cards.number as number, credit_cards.user_id as user_id FROM "users" left join credit_cards on credit_cards.user_id = users.id
```

Database result

```
id | number | user_id 
----+--------+---------
  1 | 1      |       1
  1 | 2      |       1
  2 | 1      |       2
  2 | 2      |       2
  3 | 1      |       3
  3 | 2      |       3
(6 rows)
```

Answer (score 10):

Since go-gorm has a certain [convention](https://gorm.io/docs/conventions.html#Column-Name) when it comes to naming, you might want to try two things.

Make your `res` struct publicly available, with public fields:

```
type Res struct{
    ID int
    Number int
    UserID int
}
```

Or, specify mappings between columns and fields:

```
type res struct{
    id int      `gorm:"column:id"`
    number int  `gorm:"column:number"`
    user_id int `gorm:"column:user_id"`
}
```

Comment: It worked thank you for help.
Changing the name to Pascal case works but adding gorm column tags did not work

Comment: @pariks You can accept the answer if it helped you even if it contains extra information that you found useless.

Answer (score 1):

`gorm` can only read/write on [exported fields](https://tour.golang.org/basics/3) much like `Marshal`/`Unmarshal` methods of `json` package. If the first letter of your field is in capital, it will be used. By default, `gorm` matches struct fields with their camel-cased forms. You can also define your own [column names](https://gorm.io/docs/conventions.html#Column-Name).

Since camel-cased form of both `ID` and `Id`, is `id`, as long as the first letter of your field is in capital, it should work. On a different note, it's good practice to write `ID`, i.e., both letter capital.